# PHP: Can I reference a single member of an array that is returned by a function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

any idea how if the following is possible in PHP as a single line ?:

```
<?php
$firstElement = functionThatReturnsAnArray()[0];
```

... It doesn't seem to 'take'. I need to do this as a 2-stepper:

```
<?php
$allElements = functionThatReturnsAnArray();
$firstElement = $allElements[0];
```

... just curious - other languages I play with allow things like this, and I'm lazy enoug to miss this in PHP ... any insight appreciated ...

Comment: Upgrade to PHP 5.4 and you can then do [array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html). You can [find it in the manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-87).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$firstElement = reset(functionThatReturnsAnArray());
```

If you're just looking for the first element of the array.

Comment: agreed - and in my case this actually works pretty well. Thx so much for this!

Comment: Lovely. Huge refactoring tonight then!

Comment: It works but now you have to spend extra brain cycles to translate from reset(func()) to func()[0] when you look at the code.

Answer (score 9):

@Scott Reynen

that's not true. This will work:

```
list(,,$thirdElement) = $myArray;
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, that is not possible with PHP. You have to use two lines to do it.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the flaws with PHP.

Comment: well, it's a pain, but it's not a show-stopper really is it? I mean, given the reputation of PHP for poorly-formed and badly managed code, maybe it's a good thing! :p

Comment: actually, the other answers pointing me to list & reset work well - not pretty, but they do what i want them to :-) I love this web site !

Answer (score 5):

You *can* do this in one line! Use [array_shift()](http://us.php.net/array_shift).

```
<?php

echo array_shift(i_return_an_array());

function i_return_an_array() {
    return array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
}
```

When this is executed, it will echo "`foo`".

Answer (score 3):

list() is useful here. With any but the first array element, you'll need to pad it with useless variables. For example:

```
list( $firstElement ) = functionThatReturnsAnArray();
list( $firstElement , $secondElement ) = functionThatReturnsAnArray();
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Either `current($array)` or `array_shift($array)` will work, the former will leave the *array* intact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_slice()`, like so:

```
$elementX = array_slice(functionThatReturnsAnArray(), $x, 1);
```

Also noticed that `end()` is not mentioned. It returns the last element of an array.

Answer (score 1):

I actually use a convenience function i wrote for such purposes:

```
/**
 * Grabs an element from an array using a key much like array_pop
 */
function array_key_value($array, $key) {
    if(!empty($array) && array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        return $array[$key];
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

then you just call it like so:

```
$result = array_key_value(getMeAnArray(), 'arrayKey');
```

Answer (score 0):

nickf, good to know, thanks. Unfortunately that has readability problems beyond a few commas.

Comment: yeah that's very true - i avoid it whenever I can, but it's still possible! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found a couple of ways to get what you want without calling another function.

```
$firstElement = ($t = functionThatReturnsAnArray()) ? $t[0] : false;
```

and for strings you could use

```
$string = (($t = functionThatReturnsAnArray())==0) . $t[0];
```

.. Interesting problem

Draco

Answer (score 0):

I think any of the above would require a comment to explain what you're doing, thus becoming two lines. I find it simpler to do:

```
$element = functionThatReturnsArray();
$element = $element[0];
```

This way, you're not using an extra variable and it's obvious what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstItem = current(returnsArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this is a built-in or library function, since it sounds like you cannot edit it directly.  I recommend creating a wrapper function to give you the output you need:

```
function functionThatReturnsOneElement( $arg )
{
    $result = functionThatReturnsAnArray( $arg );
    return $result[0];
}
$firstElement = functionThatReturnsOneElement();
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know this is not possible, I have wanted to do this myself several times.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.php.net/reset

Only available in php version 5.

Answer (score -1):

If it's always the first element, you should probably think about having the function return just the first item in the array. If that is the most common case, you could use a little bit of coolness:

```
function func($first = false) {
    ...
    if $first return $array[0];
    else return $array;
}

$array = func();
$item = func(true);
```

My php is slightly rusty, but i'm pretty sure that works.

You can also look at array_shift() and array_pop().

This is probably also possible:

```
array(func())[0][i];
```

The 0 is for the function.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes I'll change the function, so it can optionally return an element instead of the entire array:

```
<?php
function functionThatReturnsAnArray($n = NULL) {
  return ($n === NULL ? $myArray : $myArray[$n]);
}
$firstElement = functionThatReturnsAnArray(0);
```