# Most efficient way to index a returned array?

Tags: php

```
function returnsAnArray ()
{
  return array ('test');
}

echo returnsAnArray ()[0];
```

generates a syntax error in PHP. What's the most efficient way to directly obtain an element from a returned array without assigning the result to a temp variable?

Comment: How can there be a syntax error when there actually is no syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way, using the [list](http://www.php.net/list) language construct

```
function returnsAnArray ()
{
  return array ('test');
}

list($foo)=returnsAnArray();
```

You could grab a sequence of elements from an offset by combining this with [array_slice](http://www.php.net/array_slice)

```
list($third,$fourth,$fifth)=array_slice(returnsAnArray(), 2, 3);
```

Comment: This is actually a very nice way to access an array. I've seen people stumble with it, though, maybe because it falls outside of the standard C-flavor syntax (i.e. something assigned to a function).

Comment: So how do you generalize it to access the `$n`th value from the array?

Comment: You could use array_slice, e.g. list($third)=array_slice(returnsAnArray(), 2, 1);

Comment: Ok this is valid to access known positioned items. What about to access known index from associated array getting returned from a function?

Answer (score 3):

Define a new function for returning a specific index from an array.

```
function arr_index($arr, $i) { return $arr[$i]; }
```

You might want to add some error and type checking there.

And then use it like this:

```
echo arr_index(returnsAnArray(), 0);
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: this is one of the reason i dislike php. this should be a language builtin. (or at least let us do something like fReturnsArray()[1] ...

Answer (score 1):

This will work if there is only one member in the array:

```
 <?php
 echo current(returnsAnArray());
 ?>
```

Comment: Nope, it won't. current() expects reference, therefore value cannot be passed. Returning & from returnsAnArray() may work, though.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
<?php
echo reset(functionThatReturnsAnArray());
?>
```

Similar thread: [PHP: Can I reference a single member of an array that is returned by a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711/php-can-i-reference-a-single-member-of-an-array-that-is-returned-by-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

For regular numerically indexed arrays, where func() returns such an array and $n is the index you want:

`array_pop(array_slice(func(),$n,1));`

For associative arrays (e.g. strings or other things as keys), or numeric arrays that aren't numbered and complete from 0..n, it's a little more convoluted. Where $key is the key you want:

`array_pop(array_intersect_keys(func(),Array($key => ""));`

This would also work for the first case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this for an indexed array of unknown length.

```
foreach ( returnsAnArray() as $item )
  echo $item;
```

Answer (score -1):

I ask myself why one would like to avoid creating a temporary variable for a returned array. Why don't you just return one value instead of an whole array? Maybe you'll have to overthink your program logic.

Or is it a performance/memory issue? Consider using [references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) instead of always creating a new array object and returning it.

Comment: The actual function is used to parse a resultset, in some specific cases I know I'll only be returning a single entry. I could refactor the solution to use a distinct function for single results, but felt I'd end up with either duplicate or convoluted code.