# PHP - How to get object from array when array is returned by a function?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, function

how can I get a object from an array when this array is returned by a function?

```
class Item {
    private $contents = array('id' => 1);

    public function getContents() {
        return $contents;
    }
}

$i = new Item();
$id = $i->getContents()['id']; // This is not valid?

//I know this is possible, but I was looking for a 1 line method..
$contents = $i->getContents();
$id = $contents['id'];
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711/php-can-i-reference-a-single-member-of-an-array-that-is-returned-by-a-function

Comment: It's `return $this->contents;`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the 2-line version. Unless you have a compelling reason to squash your code down, there's no reason *not* to have this intermediate value.

However, you could try something like

```
$id = array_pop($i->getContents())
```

Comment: How does array_pop know that it has to output 'id' ?

Comment: array_pop will return the first element in the array, whether it's indexed numerically $x[0] or associatively $['id']. see http://php.net/array_pop for more on how it works. Now, if your class can do further manipulation to the private variable $contents then this may not be reliable, but based on what you have here array_pop will give you the contents of $contents['id']

Comment: Ok well the class is a bit bigger then displayed :). I ended up creating a Item($index) function which returns the item. $i->getContents()->Item('id');

Comment: array_pop returns the LAST element, not the first.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it at two lines - if you have to access the array again, you'll have it there. Otherwise you'll be calling your function again, which will end up being uglier anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but my one line soulution for this would be:

**PHP >= 5.4**

Your soulution should work with PHP >= 5.4

```
$id = $i->getContents()['id'];
```

**PHP < 5.4**:

```
class Item
{
    private $arrContents = array('id' => 1);

    public function getContents()
    {
        return $this->arrContents;
    }

    public function getContent($strKey)
    {
        if (false === array_key_exists($strKey, $this->arrContents)) {
            return null; // maybe throw an exception?
        }

        return $this->arrContents[$strKey];
    }
}

$objItem = new Item();
$intId   = $objItem->getContent('id');
```

Just write a method to get the value by key.

Best regards.