# Access array element that's returned from a function right from the function call

Tags: php, arrays, function

Is there a way to access a specific element of an array that's returned from a function in PHP right from the function call? Let's say I have a function called `getMostRecentPost()` and it returns an array. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
echo getMostRecentPost()['title'];
```

That doesn't work. Other languages seem to allow this kind of syntax though. Right now my solution is to do this:

```
$mostRecentPost = getMostRecentPost();
echo $mostRecentPost['title'];
```

Are there any shortcuts that will allow me to cut out declaring a variable? Do I have my syntax wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Can I reference a single member of an array that is returned by a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711/php-can-i-reference-a-single-member-of-an-array-that-is-returned-by-a-function)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971489/php-how-to-get-object-from-array-when-array-is-returned-by-a-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664362/access-an-array-returned-by-a-function

Comment: Whoops, guess I shouldn't have opened this question so quickly. My fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's **possible** with PHP 5.4, [quoting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> **As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a
>   function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a
>   temporary variable.**

**Example from php.net:**

```
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];
```

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do it with objects. If getMostRecentPost() returned an object you could go

```
echo getMostRecentPost()->title;
```

Comment: Well...I guess I could refactor and change my code to use classes instead

Answer (score 0):

It's a new feature in php 5.4

```
function arr(){return [5];}
echo arr()[0];
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/z6xPrL